# Reorder factors by a group statistic

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, forcats

I know this should be straightforward, but it always bites me.
Suppose I have a factor:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
fruits <- as.factor(c("apples", "oranges", "oranges", "pears", "pears", "pears"))
df <- as.data.frame(fruits)
```

I want to reorder the factors according to their frequency (or some other statistics) so that pears>oranges>apples. How do I do that *without* explicitly calling `df %>% group_by(fruits) %>% summarise(freq = n()) %>% fct_reorder(fruits, freq, .desc = TRUE)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may need to use that in `mutate`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
out <- df %>% 
   group_by(fruits) %>% 
   summarise(freq = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
   mutate(fruits = fct_reorder(fruits, freq, .desc = TRUE))
```

-checking the order of `levels`

```
levels(out$fruits)
[1] "pears"   "oranges" "apples" 
levels(df$fruits)
[1] "apples"  "oranges" "pears"
```

---

If we want to do this on the original dataset, instead of `summarise`, use `add_count` to create a frequency column, and apply `fct_reorder`

```
df <- df %>% 
    add_count(fruits) %>% 
    mutate(fruits = fct_reorder(fruits, n, .desc = TRUE)) %>% 
    select(-n)
```

NOTE: `group_by` in `1.0.6` - `dplyr` version doesn't have a `.desc` argument.  The `.desc` is found in `fct_reorder`

---

In `base R`, we can do this with `table`

```
out1 <- table(fruits)
factor(fruits, levels = names(out1[order(-out1)]))
[1] apples  oranges oranges pears   pears   pears  
Levels: pears oranges apples
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I did not explain well. I want to preserve the original (ungrouped) dataset of n=6 so that if I sort by fruits, it doesn't sort alphabetically

Comment: @ThomasSpeidel Sorry, I thought you want to summarised first.  You can do `df %>% add_count(fruits) %>% mutate(fruits = fct_reorder(fruits, n, .desc = TRUE)) %>% select(-n)`

Comment: Thanks! If you want to put it as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: @ThomasSpeidel I already added the solution in the post. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think we can also do this with `fct_infreq`:

```
library(forcats)

df %>%
  {fct_infreq(.$fruits)}

[1] apples  oranges oranges pears   pears   pears  
Levels: apples oranges pears
```

Or maybe this one:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(fruits = fruits %>% 
           fct_infreq() %>% 
           fct_rev()) %>% 
  pull(fruits)

   fruits
1  apples
2 oranges
3 oranges
4   pears
5   pears
6   pears
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I don't know why this `df %>%
  mutate(fruits = fruits %>% fct_infreq() %>% fct_rev())` won't work and I have to use `arrange` to reverse the order.

Comment: I think I have to erase it, as this is irrelavent.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think the second one is much better.